# redux-actions library combine-actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-actions

I'm trying to setup redux-actions library.
[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-1wxsh) is my code. The problem is that my combine actions reacts only to first argument.
Example:

```
[combineActions(types.DECREASE, types.DECREASE2)]
```

In this case it will react only to DECREASE and if

```
[combineActions(types.DECREASE2, types.DECREASE)]
```

only to DECREASE2.
What am I missing?

Comment: look for this documentation: https://redux-actions.js.org/api/combineactions

Comment: @Nemer it's quite nice to send link to docs, which is obvious... I've already discovered that this problem is related to prefixing actions, as without prefixing it works as intended.

Comment: Fixed it for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/reactredux-b4k3q. I believe the issue here was adding the prefix incorrectly.

Comment: @Kyle, thank you very much:)